# Transferring serialized objects with jboss much faster than transferring byte arrays?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

Following scenario:

I have a java client with 40 threads. Each thread has its own bean instance and each thread calls its beans method 100 times. 
I'm confused about the results of this test because sending objects turned out to be a lot faster than sending byte arrays or integer arrays. Sending a single integer value is still fastest, though. The size of both arrays in this test was 1. Size 2048 was neither slower nor faster.
map, data, panel, maprecord and field are classes with quite a lot of properties.

How can this be?

static: created once, server always returns same instance
dynamic: created everytime the beans method is called

```
sessions: 40
repetitions: 100
transactions: 4000

send bytes ( static )
transactions/s: 1047.3947
time: 3.819

send ints ( dynamic )
transactions/s: 11976.048
time: 0.334

send int arrays ( static )
transactions/s: 1114.5166
time: 3.589

send map with 30 fields ( static )
transactions/s: 4613.6104
time: 0.867

send map, created from panel ( dynamic )
transactions/s: 221.50847
time: 18.058

send data, containing a map created from a maprecord ( dynamic )
transactions/s: 5797.1016
time: 0.69
```

My javax.ejb.EJBObject:

```
...
public byte[] getByteArrayForPerformanceTest() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
public Map getMapForPerformanceTest() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
public Data getConverseDataForPerformanceTest() throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
...
```

The UserSessionBean:

```
...
private static byte[] byteArrayForPerformanceTest = new byte[1];

public byte[] getByteArrayForPerformanceTest() throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
    return UserSessionBean.byteArrayForPerformanceTest;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your Collections, Maps, and arrays are all serializable, as well as the primitives. It's more likely that JBoss uses standard Java serialization to send/receive these instances between remote entitites. If you wan't an explanation as to why one thing goes faster than other, then why don't you serialize both those instances to separate files and see which one is bigger. Especially with collections and maps you can't know how many objects (especially arrays) are created under the hood when you instantiate them. Note that for these you can controll to some point the initial sizes of the underlying arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what is under the hood here but you might for example be serializing your objects to byte arrays then sending those and JBoss is serializing *them*, so two serialization step.s